# Late Yom Hatzmaut

Tags: calendar, yom-haatzmaut

What is the rule: when is Yom Hatzmaut moved from the fifth of Iyar to an earlier or later date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove any possibility of observances of either [Yom Ha'atzmaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Ha%27atzmaut) or the preceding day's [Yom Hazikaron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Hazikaron) spilling either forward or back into Shabbat and thereby causing public Shabbat desecration, the Israeli Chief Rabbinate [determined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Ha%27atzmaut#Timing) that Yom Ha'atzmaut should never fall on a Shabbat, Sunday, Monday, or Friday. So, if 5 Iyyar is on a Friday or Shabbat, the holiday moves back to Thursday. If 5 Iyyar is on a (Sunday [impossible in our current calendar] or) Monday, it moves forward to Tuesday.

Comment: And the position of the Rabbinical Council of America is that Diaspora Jews should observe Yom Ha'atzmeut the same day that Israelis do so. http://www.rabbis.org/news/article.cfm?id=105487

Comment: Though some notable rabbis, both in Israel and the Diaspora, differ and insist on strict observance on the 5th of Iyar no matter what; (see http://torahmusings.com/2011/05/technology-halakhic-change-and-yom-ha-atzmaut/); but the standard official position is as Isaac stated, whether in Israel or outside.

Comment: On what basis do you say that if 5 Iyyar falls on a Sunday, Yom HaAtzmaut is moved to Tuesday?  I could just as easily assert that if 5 Iyyar falls on a Sunday, Yom HaAtzmaut is moved to the previous Thursday, and we would both be correct, because (as you correctly state) the current calendar does not allow 5 Iyyar to fall on Sunday.  My point is that there is no official statement about what happens to Yom HaAtzmaut in that case, because the case never occurs.

Comment: @AriBrodsky Moving it back to Thursday would place Yom haZikaron on Rosh Chodesh. Isaac's extrapolation is very well based.