# Dancing on Yom Haatzmaus

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, mourning-aveilus, yom-haatzmaut, dance

One is not allowed to dance during the mourning days of *s'firas haomer* ([*Mishna B'rura* 493:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=196)). According to all major customs, *Yom Haatzmaus* (Israel's independence day) falls during the mourning days (as it's the [third, fourth, fifth, or sixth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7121) of *Iyar*; see e.g. [*MB* 493:14–15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=197)). Yet some orthodox synagogues and schools have programs on *Yom Haatzmaus* in which people are encouraged to dance.

Now, a *sandek* is allowed to shave in honor of the *b'ris mila* ([*MB* 493:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=197)), but AFAICT dancing is still forbidden to him.

So my first question is:

- Are the mourning restrictions dropped completely by those who allow dancing on *Yom Haatzmaus*, much as they are on, e.g., *lag baomer*, or is it only dancing that's permitted (in honor of the day, much as shaving is permitted for a *sandek* in honor of the *b'ris mila*)?

Now, the custom is to observe mourning restrictions thirty-three days; *which* thirty-three days varies by custom. See e.g. [*MB* 493:14–15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=197). The examples he gives, though, count *lag baomer* as one of the thirty-three days even if mourning restrictions are not kept during its daylight hours, because mourning restrictions *are* kept during its evening ([*MB* 493:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=197), but see [:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&pgnum=197)). So **if** the answer to my first question is that all mourning restrictions are dropped on *Yom Haatzmaus*, my next questions are:

- Are all mourning restrictions dropped from *Yom Haatzmaus* both evening and day?
- Is *Yom Haatzmaus*, like *lag baomer*, counted as one of the thirty-three days with restrictions? Or do those who keep no restrictions on *Yom Haatzmaus* count thirty-three days of restrictions besides it?

(Of course, because of the considerations in the paragraph just above, these last two questions are of interest in light of one another.)

A sourced answer (e.g. citing a *t'shuva* addressing these issues) would be ideal, but an answer telling what people do generally is also of interest.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27569

Comment: Worth noting that shaving can be considered related to the celebration of Yom Ha'atzmaut (looking nice), unlike, say, getting married on a day your son has a bris, which would only be allowed if the restrictions are pushed off as a group.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28498

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37731

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57632

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58060/discussion-on-question-by-msh210-dancing-on-yom-haatzmaus).

Answer (score 2):

In the Sefer Halachos Yom Ha'Atzmaus V'Yom Yerushalayim page 334-340 the Rishon L'Tziyon HaRav Yitzchak Nissim says that all Minhagim of Aveilus are suspended for the day.

[Per Rav Shmuel Katz from the Rabanut Hareishis L'Yisroel](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/ezrachut/harabanut3-2.htm) it is permissible.

‏'יום המדינה' ה' אייר שחל בימי הספירה, שלפי דיני ישראל נוהגים בהם אבילות, יהא דינו כיום ל"ג בעומר, ולפי החלטת הרבנות הראשית יותרו כל השמחות, חגיגות נישואין תספורת וכו'‏

However [Rav Ronan Nubirt](http://web.archive.org/web/20131001185813/https://www.ypt.co.il/show.asp?id=27393) says that you would be required to hold a different day of Sefira to make up for it. היוצא מכל הנ"ל, שהנוהג היתר בחגי הגאולה, יום העצמאות ויום ירושלים, לכאורה צריך להשלים אותם ימים, ואולי צריך להשלים אף את ערבי החגים הללו שבהם נהגו להתגלח לכבוד החג

*This answer is applicable to those that celebrate Yom Ha'Atzmaot and want to know what sources they have that permit it.*

Comment: Thanks. Is "יהא דינו כיום ל"ג בעומר" meant to imply that the lifting of mourning restrictions is only for the daylight hours and that _Yom Haatzmaus_ counts as one of the thirty-three restricted days?

Comment: ...and the same question about Rabbi _Nisim_'s ruling.

Comment: @msh210 I doubt it. Leil Yom Haatzmaut is when the larger dancing parties happen in Israel (mostly). The day is usually for BBQ and tiyulim with friends and family.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so you doubt, then, that the restrictions are lifted for the daytime only. Any idea whether _Yom Haatzmaus_ counts as one of days of mourning, then? ¶ On another note, I'm not sure whether the quotation from the _rabanus_ is correct. The footnote on the text quoted here reads (in part) "הרבנות הראשית חזרה בה מהיתר זה [ראה בהמשך]‏", though I don't see that particular המשך.‎

Comment: I don't get the point of the disclaimer at the end of this answer. This answer is not pesak and therefore not "applicable" to anyone. And it's self-evident that sources detailing the observance of Y"H are only relevant in the context of discussing the observance of Y"H.

Comment: Even with disclaimers there are those that may take it for Pesak, and I do not want to be responsible for something I personally disagree with.

Comment: What about those who celebrate and want to know if the heterim they use cover non-celebratory sefira restrictions or not? (ie these aren't people looking to justify celebratory practices; your disclaimer has an unclear pronoun at the end)