# Dancing during kidush levana on sefiras haomer

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, kiddush-levanah

After making kidush levana there is a custom to dance and sing a song "Tovim meorot...". Is it permissible to dance after kidush levana of the month of Iyar, as it falls during the mourning days of sefiras haomer?

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/dancing-on-yom-haatzmaus) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Halachaicly Speaking](http://thehalacha.com/attach/Volume5/Issue9.pdf) : One is permitted to dance after kiddush levana even during sefira 
(Piskei Shmuos quoting the opinion of Harav D’bilitsky Shlita)

Comment: Is this only on Motza"sh or also during the week?

Comment: It seems the whole week,because it is a mitzvah

Comment: +1. Can you link to the _Halachically Speaking_ (if it's online) please?

Comment: http://thehalacha.com/attach/Volume5/Issue9.pdf ,footnote 34

Comment: @sam, thanks, and jutky's edited it into your answer. (In the future, generally, if someone asks for more information in a comment, he means for it to be added to the answer, where it belongs.)

Comment: ok no problem  you got it