# What Should One Do If He Forgot to Say "VeYiten Lekha" on Saturday Night

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, maariv, havdalah, motzei-shabbos

According to those who observe the custom of reciting the passage of *VeYiten Lekha* on Motzaei Shabbat before or after Havdalah, what should one do if s/he forgot to recite it?  I have never seen anyone recite this section after that time (e.g., not on Monday morning), so is there no such thing as tashlumin (make-up) for this if one missed it?

A friend of mine suggested to me that maybe it is like Keriyat Shema, and that there is nothing wrong with just reading pesukim, because it is just like learning Torah.

Comment: Well, I think your friend is on to something. But what makes you think you need to do anything? What does one do if he forgets to say 'Aleinu or LeDavid?

Comment: It seems to me that there is no way to make it up, because with Shmoneh Esreh, you can make it up if you forgot to say it. The Shulchan Aruch rules that you can do the same with Asher Yatzar, but all the acharonim disagree. It is implied (by the Shu"A not ruling the same way for other cases) that he thinks Asher Yatzar is the only case where you could do it. It comes out using this reasoning that everyone agrees that you can't make it up.

On the other hand, VeYiten Lecha is connected to havdalah, so shouldn't its law be connected, i.e. that you can say it until Tuesday, just like havdalah?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I noticed your edit; why are you hating on Motzash?

Comment: @AdamMosheh de-jargonify

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - It's not jargon, it's *Rashei Teivot*.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin @HodofHod AdamMosheh: What if we just call it Saturday night and forget about it?` That is definitely the least jargon-y we could be.

Comment: @msh210 Motzash is definitely a popular Israeli acronym. But even so, I stand by my previous comment.

Comment: @msh210 It seems I've used it once before around here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15957/dancing-during-kidush-levana-on-sefiras-haomer#comment32725_15960

Comment: @msh210 - The Hebrew Wikipedia here says that Motzash is indeed an acronym for Motzaei Shabbat: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA

Comment: @AdamMosheh Its being defined doesn't show that it's used.

Comment: AdamMosheh, @DoubleAA: מוצ״ש I've seen often; _Motza"sh_ (with the quotation marks to indicate it's a transliteration of a Hebrew acronym) sometimes; _Motzash_ never AFAIR. But that could just be me.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I suppose so, but I have friends who say Motzash. [Unless...](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/773/will-there-ever-be-a-meet-up#comment1679_773)

Comment: @msh210 - What's the difference when it is a spoken phrase? When it is written in Hebrew, use the quotation mark, but in English do whatever you want.

Comment: @msh210 I'm not sure that we're disagreeing, but just to clarify, many Israelis refer to Saturday night as Motzash pronounced as one word, like we would say LASER or RADAR. How you want to transliterate it is a separate discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my observation of what people do in general (and instructions in *machzorim*), they do not say "*V'yiten l'cha*" after the end of a *yom tov* which is Sunday (or Sunday and Monday, or *Shabas* and Sunday), nor on *motzae Shabas* which is *yom tov*. Thus, it seems to me that there is no make-up for "*V'yiten l'cha*". Of course, one can distinguish that case from the case in which one neglected to say it, but absent other evidence I think this is pretty telling. (I do look forward to other evidence, though, in other answers.)