# Can an non-North African Jew participate in post-Pesach Mimouna celebrations?

Tags: halacha, passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, parties-celebrations

[Mimouna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimouna) is a customary post-Pesach celebration originally observed by Moroccan and Algerian Jews. When large numbers of those groups made aliyah, the custom was adopted by many Israelis as well.

The celebration focuses on being able to eat chametz again, with traditional foods, costumes, symbols, and music.

However, this happens to fall during Sfira, when parties and celebrations with loud music are customarily avoided.

Apparently, the North African communities have a long-standing tradition to celebrate this. But what about other groups? Is there a problem because of Sfira?

Comment: Very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27569