# Does a siyyum in the 9 days obviate other issurim?

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, nine-days, siyum, simchah-joy-happiness

Each year, I try to coordinate my learning so that I can make a seudat mitzvah during the nine days and some close friends can have some meat and wine to celebrate. Does the siyum also allow them to listen to music, do laundry etc? What if the live music was part of the siyum (inasmuch as it enhances the simcha of the moment)? Does the siyum change the nature of that entire day for the participants, or just the time at the siyum? Does it make the time at the siyum as if it is not in the nine days, or just allow a particular type of behavior on top of the other issurim of the day?

Comment: parallel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15942/759

Comment: Do you serve meat and wine when you make siyumim at other times of the year? Do you have live music and dancing at those siyumim?

Comment: Live music has happened. I don't dance, though. 2.5 left feet.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: If I have a siyyum because of learning during the rest of the year, and there is any food (I have been involved in ones which lack food), there is usually meat. I can't speak to wine, though.

Comment: @DoubleAA 
אין שמחה אלא בבשר ויין.

Comment: @SethJ So? I've been to Siyumim without meat.

Comment: @DoubleAA, how sad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rama writes meat and wine by a seudas mitzvah davka and the food can only be eaten in the room of the siyum(Mishna Brurah 551:75).It seems that meat and wine are the only exception and it only applies during the seudah,not the rest of the day.

It should be noted that planning a siyum to davka come out during the nine days is not so pashut,even though there are those who are matir.

Comment: Which parts are the Rama saying and which are the MB saying?

Comment: I am interested in the "not so pashut" part of your answer. What are the issues?

Comment: @DoubleAA Having looked it up: Rema says: those 'appropriate to the meal' can have meat & wine, but it should be reduced, and in the week 9 Av falls only an exact minyan.  MB says those who would have been invited to the siyum normally may go, but not others.  If wmen would be invited, they too can partake, but no one may bring meat home to eat during the 9 Days.