# Will Tisha B'Av be pushed off in the future?

Tags: shabbat, messiah, tisha-bav, chagim-holidays

We have a tradition that Tisha B'Av will become a holiday in the time of Moshiach. Will that holiday also be nidcheh if it comes out on Shabbos?

Comment: When do you see a yom tov pushed off?

Comment: @sam Maybe Purim Meshulash?

Comment: Note that at that time we will probably be setting the calendar based on witnesses so any of the 4 fasts/holidays could fall on Shabbat.

Comment: @sam I'm not sure what sort of holiday (i.e. full "yom tov" or not) TB"A will be, or who will determine the rules for it, but one precedent that may be cited at the time would be Yom Ha'atzmaut, which [is pushed off](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/late-yom-hatzmaut) to honor Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA, don't you mean [Mishlesh](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13933/5)? ;-D

Comment: @IsaacMoses Is Yom Ha'atzmaut pushed off to honor Shabbat or to avoid extra Shabbat desecration? Those are very different IMO.

Comment: @SethJ I figure in this case it is reminiscent of a [Hamentashen](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/why-does-a-hamentash-have-three-sides).

Comment: @DoubleAA We honor Shabbat by not desecrating it. We preserve that honor by avoiding promotion of additional desecration.

Comment: @IsaacMoses We don't know if they will be gozer or not (a decision which will be made with the circumstances of that time in mind). What we can discuss is if there is some fundamental contradiction with a holiday on Shabbat, and Yom Ha'atzmaut doesn't seem to help answer that question.

Comment: I have to double check the work "Caught in the Crack" but apparently shabbetai tzvi (yemach shemo) actually declared tisha b'av to be a chag and everyone who was under his sway at the time celebrated it, including prominent rabbanim. if i'm not mistaken that year it was on shabbos.

Comment: I think the underlying question is what the nature of the yom tov will be -- will it be like pesach which is not pushed off and is a full yom tov, or like purim (shushan purim in a walled city) which is pushed off and is only a "holiday" not a yom tov. each commemorates a victory over evil, but only pesach is a celebration of a real ge'ulah, much like Tish'a b'av will be. so my vote is full yom tov and not pushed off.

Comment: @Dan, I'm not sure why you need to create a new "chakira" in what level of holiday does and doesn't get pushed off.  Tisha b'av has a very practical reason why we do not celebrate on Shabbos- we don't mourn or create fasts on Shabbos.  For Purim, we do not read megilla on shabbos for the same reason we do not blow shofar or take a lulav on Shabbos.

Comment: @PM The first tisha bav celebrated as a holiday by the sabbateans was 1666 on a Tuesday. Celebrations continued for the next few years, slowly converting (groan) back to mourning. Tisha bav was a nidche in the years 1667 1670 and 1673 so it's possible if not likely that at least some celebrators were still around those years.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Megillah 5a says that the reason we push off Tishah be-Av is because  אקדומי פורענות לא מקדמי. In other words, since you cannot fast on Shabbos, Tishah be-av must be changed, and since it is a sad time, we push it off instead of moving it forward. Since this reason will not apply in the days of mashiach, there will be no reason to push it off.

Comment: No, that's the reason to push it forward instead of backward, not why it can't be on Shabbat.

Comment: Also, how do you know there aren't other reasons that may come into play then, which are not in play now?

Comment: Wouldn't that render any question about the future meaningless? How do you know anything about halakhah if not based on the sources that exist, in the current world?

Comment: It would not because perhaps there are other sources which you may have overlooked which discuss the future explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

BS"D

Baised off of already set Halakha ( inlight of the fact that most likely when fast days become Yom Ttov's there will be a reinstated Sanhedrin who could change existing Halakha)
The answer is simply no.

From what we know of about the 9th of av changing:
**"Thus saith the HaShem of hosts: The fast of the fourth month, and the fast of the fifth, and the fast of the seventh, and the fast of the tenth, shall be to the house of Judah joy and gladness, and cheerful seasons"**-*Zekharyah 8:19*

Not giving any depths or details what these new joyful days actually are and still staying in the parameters of the currently established Halakhic system its safe to say that they like other Holidays would not get pushed off. 
As far as Halakhic sources as to why any Yom Ttov would be postponed, I know of none.
This is all stating that the fast days become full Yom Ttov's and not remembrance days such as Purim or Hhanukah.

Answer (score -1):

No one knows yet, but there will be no reason to postpone it since the only reason to postpone is that mourning is not allowed on Shabbat.

Comment: Purim is a positive holiday which is pushed off from Shabbat!