# Can you make an Upsherin during Sefira?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sefirat-ha-omer, upsherin

Suppose a boys birthday is 6 Iyar, which is on a date that all observe mourning practices in Sefiras Homer. For those that do not give a haircut to a child until the child is three, can they make an Upsherin on the birthday? If not should it be done before Pesach, Lag Ba'Omer or some other time? (sources)

Comment: Considering many children have their first hair cut on lag b'omer in miron and I dont think all their birthdays are then that should answer your question.

Comment: @preferred: How does that answer my question? Many who do the haircut in Miron their birthdays are not even during Sefira. Many do their haircuts at home. Many, like you do it before the third birthday. I appreciate your comments, however they do not answer this question.

Comment: You may want to not use [6 _Iyar_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7121) as your example, in light of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15942.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or letzion (3:17 3) writes that all children may have haircuts during sefirah since aveilus does not apply to children. However rav Elyashiv (hilchos  chag  bechag 7 fun 58) that it should be avoided  unless there's a need like an upsherin

According to Arizal the upsherin is delayed to lag baomer.

See dirshu edition mishna beturah 493 note 18

Comment: can you explain why children dont wear shoes on tisha b'av.

Comment: @preferred  Great point! Magen AVraham (551, 38) asks why children don't get haircuts during nine days (551, 14) but don't observe Avilus for parent (Yoreh Deah 384:5). He answers that Avelus for public mourning (for Churban Bais Hamikdash [Aruch Hashulchan 31]) is stricter. The Sefira which commemorates the deaths of Rabbi Akiva's talmidim, then, is thus viewed as a lesser aveilus than a parent's.

Comment: Lesser than parents or lesser than nine days.

Comment: @preferred Lesser than parents (and kal vachomer less than nine days). Nine days is the anomaly because of Churban Bais Hamikdah

Comment: I would have thought the words are 'public' mourning which include the sefira.

Comment: @preferred Agreed. I would have thought that, too. But that's why I quotes the Aruch hashulachan who explains it as referring to Churban

Comment: True but he doesnt say it does not refer to the omer as well. I dont think its a proper diyuk to give a heter.

Comment: @preferred I guess we need to see Or Letzion and Rav Elyashiv from the primary source! I am not sure I have access to those sefarim

Answer (score 2):

The Rivevos Ephraim 1:336 and 2:155:19 talk about this. He seems to hold that for a mitzva its mutar ,however he makes a distinction for those who live in Eretz Yisroel who usually bring their son to meron on lag baomer(even some months earlier) .If he didn't do it on lab bomer then he should wait until after Tisha b'av(the tshuvua speaks about three weeks and sefira together) this seemingly the halacha fir people in Eretz Yistoel.For someone who lives in chutz laretz it seems that it would be mutar.See it inside(I skimmed through the tshuvos) .

Answer (score 2):

*Nit'e Gavriel* has an entire chapter (chapter 12) devoted to this in [the volume on תגלחת הילדים הולכתם לחדר וסעודת החומש](http://hebrewbooks.org/46552). I can't paraphrase the whole thing here, but [his conclusion](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&pgnum=292) is that "by law it's permitted to cut his hair, but the practice is to wait until *lag baomer* or to cut his hair the day before *Pesach*".

Answer (score -1):

There Is  An Age-old Custom To Give A Three Year Old Boy His First Haircut At The Age Of Three, And Also Have The Boy Start Donning A Head Covering, A Yarmulka, As Well As Tzitzis, At All Times.

This Ceremony, Referred To By Many As The "Upsherin" (Yiddish For Haircut) Is A Joyous Occasion As The  Parents Can Begin Training The Child (Chinuch) In The Mitzvah Of Peiyos (The Sideburns Or Side Locks That Must Be Left, And Are Prohibited By The Torah To Totally Remove) As Well As Other Mitzvos.

This Is Even Deemed A Simcha To The Point Of Allowing This Haircut To Be Performed During, Or Even  Postponed Until, Chol Hamoed.(See Shulchan Aruch Siman 531:6 And Sha'arei Teshuva Os 6)  (From [www.HalachaForToday.com](http://www.HalachaForToday.com))

Comment: Welcome to MY. The question was whether it is allowed during Sefirat Haomer.